# Can I load attribute values of a Hibernate mapping file from a properties file?

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration, hibernate-mapping

Does Hibernate or the combination of Spring Framework and Hibernate (I'm working on a Java web app which uses Spring 2.5 and Hibernate 3.2) offer any mechanism for loading attribute values in Hibernate's hbm.xml mapping files from e.g. `properties` files?

More specifically some of our domain objects are mapped to a different database catalog than most of the Hibernate mapped classes. Thus we use the `catalog="secondaryCatalogName"` attribute to specify the catalog name for these classes.

We use a `database.properties` file and Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to specify the default and secondary catalog names in all of our Spring configuration. However, if I need to change the secondary catalog name, I also have to change the catalog attribute in those few hbm.xml -files. It would be great if I could use a placeholder such as `${secondary.catalog}` for the catalog attribute in the mapping files as well.

Is this possible?

Here's a simplified example using configuration snippets:

**Database structure**

```
MySQL instance
- catalog: CatalogA
    - table: TableFoo
    - table: TableBar
    - ...
- catalog: CatalogB
    - table: TableBaz
    - ...
```

**database.properties**

```
primary.catalog=CatalogA
secondary.catalog=CatalogB # <-- wish I could use this property in hbm.xml
```

**SessionFactory -configuration (Spring):**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="...hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>Foo.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Bar.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Baz.hbm.xml</value>
            ...
        </list>
    </property> 

   ...

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           ...
           <prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">${primary.catalog}</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Foo.hbm.xml:**

Hibernate mapping for a domain object in **CatalogA** (CatalogA entity mappings always work fine because of `hibernate.default_catalog` property)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Foo" table="TableFoo">
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Baz.hbm.xml:**

Hibernate mapping for a domain object in **CatalogB** (this is the problem because of the **catalog** attribute: it must change in *all* hbm.xmls of CatalogB entities if I want to use a different secondary catalog name)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Baz" table="TableBaz" catalog="CatalogB">
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `hibernate.properties` file?

In you can define other properties such as hibernate.default_schema, hibernate.default_catalog, etc,..[Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Comment: Yes, I use the hibernate.default_catalog property to configure the default catalog name for the majority of my classes. That works fine, but the problem is configuring the handful of other classes that use a different catalog name.